# Palavras sobrepostas no gráfico do software R

Tags: r, gráfico

Olá, eu fiz um gráfico no R, porém as palavras ficaram sobrepostas, gostaria de ajuda para arrumar isso. Segue o gráfico para verem como ficou. Abraço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Stephane. A sobreposição vai ocorrer apenas se você salvar a imagem com tamanho pequeno, imagino que em tamanho maior não ocorra. De qualquer forma, só temos como propor uma solução se você postar os dados e o código que usou para fazer o gráfico.

Answer (score 5):

Infelizmente não existe solução simples para isso. Em geral é preciso ajustar as posições manualmente ou utilizando algum algoritmo. Dependendo do pacote que você estiver utilizando essa possibilidade sequer existe, você teria que alterar a função do pacote na mão para ter essa flexibilidade.

Todavia, para quem usa `ggplot2`, saiu um pacote recente que tenta posicionar os labels sem conflitos, [chamado `ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html).

Veja o exemplo do pacote.

Normal:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg), color = 'red') +
  geom_text(aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando o `ggrepel`:

```
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(42)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg), color = 'red') +
  geom_text_repel(aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O pacote funciona razoavelmente bem, entretanto pode engasgar com bases de dados grandes.